# Solving inequalities involving nested modulus

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Guys how do I solve inequality that has a nested modulus sign ? I'm familiar with
single modulus, but I am quite lost here. This is an example of what I'm referring to, any help and explanation is deeply appreciated.

$\left | \left | x+5 \right | - \left | x-3 \right | \right |\leq 6$

Thanks for reading my post.

Answer (score 0):

hint use $||a|+|b||<=|a|+|b|$ or we can do it by using the fact that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$